# How do I hang my console table on top of my mirror

Tags: table, mirror

[image]

I have a floating console table and a mirror and I am trying to hang the table on top of the mirror for my entryway.

Comment: More details please. Do you want holes in the mirror?  Does the shelf come with any hanging hardware? What is the wall made of?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pictures of your actual mirror and table, what manufacturer & model numbers they are, and a link to any instruction manual for the table and mirror would help. The picture you have now looks like the mirror and table have already been hung.

Comment: It's hard to be sure about what was done in this photo. They may have drilled holes through the mirror, the mirror may actually be two pieces, or there may be something else going on

Comment: rotate the mirror and then the self 180deg each.